# Unordered Map return NULL value

Tags: c++, null, unordered-map

I have global unordered_map where I store pointers to struct's.

Data is added to the map by using COM event handler:

```
const _bstr_t oTicker(structQuoteSnap.bstrSymbol, false);
const RecentInfoMap::const_iterator it = mapRecentInfo->find(oTicker);

RecentInfo* ri;
if (it == mapRecentInfo->end()) {
    ri = new RecentInfo;        
    _tcsncpy_s(ri->Name, _countof(ri->Name), oTicker, _TRUNCATE);

    const size_t tickerLen = oTicker.length() + 1;
    const LPTSTR ticker = new TCHAR[tickerLen];
    _tcsncpy_s(ticker, tickerLen, oTicker, _TRUNCATE);

    (*mapRecentInfo)[ticker] = ri;
} else {
    ri = it->second;
}
```

In another method I get map's value by it's key:

```
const RecentInfoMap::const_iterator it = g_mapRecentInfo.find(pszTicker);
if (it == g_mapRecentInfo.end()) return nLastValid + 1;
const RecentInfo* const ri = it->second;    

assert(ri != NULL);

curDateTime.PackDate.Hour = ri->nTimeUpdate / 10000;
```

And sometimes assertion is failed because ri is NULL. I don't know why this happens. There seems to be a valid code. Please give me a suggestions.

There are unordered map functors and definition:

```
struct KeyHash {
    size_t operator()(const LPCTSTR&) const;
};

struct KeyEquals {
    bool operator()(const LPCTSTR&, const LPCTSTR&) const;
};

size_t KeyHash::operator()(const LPCTSTR& key) const {
    size_t hash = 2166136261U;
    for (LPCTSTR s = key; *s != _T('\0'); ++s) {
        hash = (hash ^ static_cast<size_t>(*s)) * 16777619U;
    }
    return hash;
};


bool KeyEquals::operator()(const LPCTSTR& x, const LPCTSTR& y) const {
    return _tcscmp(x, y) == 0;
};


typedef unordered_map<LPCTSTR, RecentInfo*, KeyHash, KeyEquals> RecentInfoMap;
```

Comment: When this happens to me I always get suspicious that there is a rouge [] access somewhere, which will initialize the value to NULL whether or not it is actually in the map.

Comment: I second that.  Often it's helpful to encapsulate a map inside a class to prevent you from using the `[]` operator - instead always call your lookup function.  You only want to write that `find` code once.

Comment: You both was right. Using operator[] is very dangerous because it puts new value (bad pointer for my code) to the map when accessing by key which is not in the map. Now my code works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Your hash value depends on the content of the struct. Probably at some point you change the content of the struct and this will lead to incosistency in internal structure of the unordered_map. What can result in strange behavior. **Hash value cannot change** in time for the same instance.

Comment: Yes, I change struct's fields but I can't understand why there are dependency between hash key and struct value.